# Storing configuration values inside array

Tags: c++, parsing, configuration

I have a config file of which will consist of three columns, and n number of lines. Each columns row has a corresponding set of values. My config file will look like this:

```
12345    10    20
67890    30    40
...
...
```

So id 12345 has corresponding values 10 and 20, and 67890 has 30 and 40.

I just want to know if there is a more efficient/shorter way to do this. I feel like I am doubling up on the vector and char array storing values here. I was trying to store each value inside a single array, but instead of storing like this in a `[1][3]` array:

```
|12345|10|20|
```

it stores like this:

```
|1|2|3|4|5|1|0|2|0|
```

Ideally I would like to store them in the first option.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("configFile.conf","r");
    
    char a[20];
    char b[20];
    char c[20];
    
    vector<string> aVect;
    vector<string> bVect;
    vector<string> cVect;
        
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    
    while(!feof(fp)){
        fscanf(fp, "%s\t%s\t%s", a, b, c);
        
        aVect.push_back(a);
        bVect.push_back(b);
        cVect.push_back(c);
        
        i++;
        j = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use `std::string` `(i)fstream`, not `char[20]` `fopen`

Comment: and I don't get how `|1|2|3|4|5|1|0|2|0|` comes? not like your code would produce that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of reading and storing the values of config files.

**eg1:**

```
struct LineData
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};
...
LineData ldata = {0};
std::vector<LineData> configFileData;
...
fscanf(fp, "%d\t%d\t%d", &ldata.a, &ldata.b, &ldata.c);
configFileData.push_back(ldata);
...
```